# C# how to set const property value from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a simple class in C# with few const properties. It is having hardcoded values right now. I had to make it dynamic so the values can be read from appsetting.json or please suggest me if any other better way.

```
public sealed class DebugConst
{
    public const string IndicatorName = "Indicator";
}
```

This const value is used in another class file as.

```
if (xx == DebugConst.IndicatorName  )
{
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
"DebugConst": {
"IndicatorName":"New Indicator"
}
```

As this is a simple class I can't use dependency injection where I can configure the section in Startup. ConfigureServies()

Can anyone suggest a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you can change the value, then by definition it cannot be const. You could make it `readonly` instead, and then it can be initialised when deserialising.

Comment: i can make it readonly but how to set the value from appsettings?

Comment: If you create an init only property in your class (e.g. `public string IndicatorName = { get; init; }`) then only your class constructor can initialize `IndicatorName` and it is read-only to everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value of a const member, if you could, then it wouldn't be constant now would it? Instead, you can make it either `readonly`, or better yet, a property with a `private set`, like so:

```cs
public class DebugConst
{
    public string IndicatorName {get; private set;}
}
```

In response to your comment on how to set the value from appsettings: You need to configure your options inside ASP.NET Core's `ConfigureServices` method. Like so:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // After this, your controllers can rely on 'IOptions<DebugConst>'
    services.AddOptions<DebugConst>().BindConfiguration(nameof(DebugConst));

    // After this your controllers can directly rely on 'DebugConst'
    services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DebugConst>>().Value);

    // If you need 'DebugConst' in this method, get it like so
    var debugConst = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DebugConst)).Get<DebugConst>();
}
```